# Аннотация Value в Spring не внедряет поля java класса

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, веб-сервер, dependency-injection

Вот структура проекта:

[image: Вот структура проекта]

Вот SpringConfig:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"controlers","database"} )
@EnableWebMvc
public class SpringConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    private final ApplicationContext ApplicationContext;
    @Autowired
    public SpringConfig(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.ApplicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver(){
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(this.ApplicationContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("views/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        templateResolver.setOrder(1);
        templateResolver.setCheckExistence(true);
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine(){
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry){
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        registry.viewResolver(resolver);
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/web-interface-res/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/web-interface-res/");

    }


}
```

В папке database лежит один класс `DatabaseConnection`, вот, собственно, и он:

```
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")
public class DatabaseConnection {
    private Connection connection;

    @Value("${db.userName}")
    private String userName;
    @Value("${db.userPassword}")
    private String userPassword;
    @Value("${db.url}")
    private String dbUrl;
    @Value("${db.databaseName}")
    private String dbName;

    public DatabaseConnection() {

        try{
            System.out.println(dbUrl);
            this.connection = DriverManager.getConnection(this.dbUrl,this.dbName,this.userPassword);
            System.out.println("Сойденение устоновлено");
        }catch (SQLException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            System.out.println("Ошибка сойденения с баззой данных");
        }
    }


}
```

Я пишу обычный web-сайт с БД и решил добавлять некоторые данные через проперти-файл, чтобы в будущем проект было легко поддерживать.

Но тут столкнулся с такой проблемой: в классе `DatabaseConnection` поля не внедряются из файла проперти, то есть, на строчке

```
System.out.println(dbUrl);
```

в консоль выводится `null`. Не могу понять, как это дело всё исправить. Если требуется дополнительная информация, то я с радостью её добавлю. Также хочу добавить, что если в классе `ControlerHello` попробовать внедрить, то это получится:

```
@Controller
@PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")
public class ControlerHello {

    @Value("${db.url}")
    private String url;

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String sayHello(){
        System.out.println(url);

        return "hello";
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String showIndexHTML(){
        return "index";
    }
}
```

То есть, когда мы откроем представление `hello`, то нам выведется на экран значение из файла проперти. Понять только не могу, почему в `DatabaseConnection`-то не работает.

Comment: Попробуйте пометить `DatabaseConnection` как `@Component`. И получать его в том месте, где требуется, посредством Dependency Injection Спринга, а не самостоятельным созданием.

Comment: я добавил анотацию @Componet но когда заливал сюда случайно не впинхнул :) но всё равно спасибо за предложение

Comment: так вы используете поля уже в конструкторе, когда они ещё не выставлены. Минимальное место, где можно использовать `@Value`-поля - это метод `@PostConstruct`. Либо вы делаете их аргументами конструктора, сохранив при этом у параметров аннотации @Value. либо переносите инициализацию подключения в @PostConstruct, потому что в текущем виде этого бина спринг займется их заполнением после выхода из конструктора

Comment: Благодарю за развернутый и понятный ответ. Всё заработало огромное спасибо. Пишу на stack overflow и вообще на форумах  первый раз так что извиняюсь за свою халатность а так же новичок в spring (не набил ещё опыт / правила которые не были рассказаны в обучающем материале). Прошу добавите данный комментарий в качестве ответа чтобы я мог пометить данный вопрос решённым.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Содержимое полей, аннотированных [@Value](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-annotation) становится доступным не сразу в конструкторе (на момент создания объекта Spring ещё не стал его "владельцем" и не может выполнить с ним какие-либо действия).

Созданный бин может считаться инициализированным самое раннее - в методе, который аннотирован [@PostConstruct](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-postconstruct-predestroy) - он вызывается Spring-ом после успешной инициализации свойств бина.

Поэтому предварительный (далеко не лучший) код `DatabaseConnection` может выглядеть так:

```java
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")
public class DatabaseConnection {
    private Connection connection;

    @Value("${db.userName}")
    private String userName;
    @Value("${db.userPassword}")
    private String userPassword;
    @Value("${db.url}")
    private String dbUrl;
    @Value("${db.databaseName}")
    private String dbName;


    @PostConstruct
    void postConstructActions(){
        try{
            System.out.println(dbUrl);
            this.connection = DriverManager.getConnection(this.dbUrl,this.dbName,this.userPassword);
            System.out.println("Соединение установлено");
        }catch (SQLException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            System.out.println("Ошибка подключения к базе данных");
        }
    }
}
```

Почему не лучший? Например - в этом коде как раз используется отложенная инициализация некоторых полей (`connection`). Потенциальный наследник этого класса может не знать об этой особенности и попробует вызвать неинициализированные данные из своего конструктора.
Плюс - в данном случае `@Value` действует аналогично `@Autowired`, а его ряд источников считает [нежелательным](https://www.google.com/search?q=spring%20%40postconstruct%20deprecated).

---

Более правильный вариант предполагает внедрение зависимостей через конструктор и, по возможности, использование final-полей:

```java
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")
public class DatabaseConnection {
    private final Connection connection;
    private final String userName;

    private final String userPassword;
    private final String dbUrl;
    private final String dbName;

    public DatabaseConnection(@Value("${db.userName}") String userName, @Value("${db.userPassword}") String userPassword, @Value("${db.url}") String dbUrl, @Value("${db.databaseName}") String dbName) {
            System.out.println(dbUrl);
            this.userName = userName; // а возможно, эти поля не нужно хранить, ведь основная цель - создать подключение
            this.userPassword = userPassword;
            this.dbUrl = dbUrl;
            this.dbName = dbName;
            
            try {
                this.connection = DriverManager.getConnection(this.dbUrl,this.dbName,this.userPassword);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e); // зачем нам запускаться, если подключения к БД нет...
            }
            System.out.println("Соединение установлено");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй добавить над классом DatabaseConnection аннотацию @Component

Comment: я добавил анотацию @Componet но когда заливал сюда случайно не впинхнул :) но всё равно спасибо за предложение.Bean создаётся делал гетр и через объект класса его вызывал там тоже значение null